# Difference between validate and validateOpt in JsValue

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.6, play-json

`JsValue` has two methods

`def validate[A](implicit rds: Reads[A]): JsResult[A]` - Tries to convert the node into a JsResult[T] (Success or Error).

`def validateOpt[A](implicit rds: Reads[A]): JsResult[Option[A]]` - I suppose it also does the same thing.

In which situation would `validateOpt` be used? In my opinion, if `JsResult` fails then I'll get the error in `JsError`. So what is the point of having an additional layer of `Option` in `JsSuccess` as `JsSuccess` will always contain value after successful conversion of `JsValue` into the type `A`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`validateOpt`](https://github.com/playframework/play-json/blob/8638769d071e86d62ff5aab0be9cd459c5a615fc/play-json/shared/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsLookup.scala#L162) should be used when a null JSON value or missing JSON path is not considered an error. For example, say we have the following model

```
case class Person(
  name: String
  employer: Option[String]
)
```

where `employer` field is optional as it is perfectly reasonable for a person not to be employed, whilst they always have a name. Then deserialising the following JSON

```
{
  "name": "Picard"
}
```

should succeed even though `employer` path is missing. Thus manually defining `Reads[Person]` would make use of `validateOpt` like so

```
  implicit val personRead: Reads[Person] = Reads { json =>
    for {
      name     <- (json \ "name").validate[String]
      employer <- (json \ "employer").validateOpt[String]
    } yield Person(name, employer)
  }
```

Also contrast deserialisation of `null`, for example

```
  val raw = "null"
  val json = Json.parse(raw)
  println(json.validate[String])
  println(json.validateOpt[String])
```

should output

```
JsError(List((,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray())))))
JsSuccess(None,)
```

where we see `validateOpt` resulted in success.

Comment: I understand the answer but I am struggling with some other scenario. Could you please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55881709/unable-to-understand-why-validateopt-will-return-none-instead-of-jserror