# unable to understand why validateOpt will return `None` instead of `JsError`

Tags: playframework-2.6

In the following code, I am unable to understand why `validateOpt` might return value `JsSuccess(None)` instead of `JsError`

```
def getQuestion = silhouette.UserAwareAction.async{ 

    implicit request => {        
      val body: AnyContent = request.body
      val jsonBodyOption: Option[JsValue] = body.asJson

      jsonBodyOption.map((jsonBody:JsValue) => { //body is json
        val personJsonJsResultOption = jsonBody.validateOpt[Person]//check that json structure is correct

        personJsonJsResultOption match {
          case personSuccessOption: JsSuccess[Option[Person]] => { //json is correct
val personOption = personSuccessOption.getOrElse(None) //why would getOrElse return None??
            personOption match {
              case Some(person) => {
...              }
              case None =>{ //I am not sure when this will be triggered.
     ...
                }
              }
            }
          }
          case e: JsError => {
        ...
            }
          }
        }
      })
      .getOrElse(//body is not json
...)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`validateOpt` by design considers success to be not only when `body` provides actual `Person` but also when `Person` is `null` or not provided. Note how [documentation](https://github.com/playframework/play-json/blob/8638769d071e86d62ff5aab0be9cd459c5a615fc/play-json/shared/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsLookup.scala#L162) explains why `JsSuccess(None)` is returned:

```
  /**
   * If this result contains `JsNull` or is undefined, returns `JsSuccess(None)`.
   * Otherwise returns the result of validating as an `A` and wrapping the result in a `Some`.
   */
  def validateOpt[A](implicit rds: Reads[A]): JsResult[Option[A]]
```

Seems like your requirement is that `Person` must **always** be provided to be considered successful, so in this case `validate` should be used instead of `validateOpt`.

Comment: Thanks. So if I use `validate`, I can be sure that `JsSuccess` will have the value. In that case, is it ok to use `get` of `JsSuccess` to get the value? The documentation does not recommend using `get` directly.

Comment: Also, could you please look at another question of mine - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55857052/how-to-test-an-actiont-without-a-message-body-in-play-framework

Comment: No need to use `get` on `JsSuccess`, instead pattern match with `case JsSuccess(person, _) =>`  and `person` will already be the unwrapped value.